# When a moderator closes a question, do they consult with the other moderators first?

Tags: discussion, closing, moderators

Shortly after [π-day 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189244) was first posted, it was closed by Daniel Fischer, a moderator, as “too broad”.  Normally five users’ votes are required to close a question, but when a moderator votes to close, as in this case, the question is closed instantly.  In this case Daniel Fischer’s vote was the only one.

> I am only curious to know whether the moderators discussed and agreed on the closure ahead of time, or if Daniel Fischer acted alone. I would also be interested to know what the moderators’ usual procedure is in cases like this.

I am not contesting, criticizing, or even complaining about this closure. Nor am I asking why it was closed.

I hope that the moderators will take this question as it was intended, purely as a request for information about moderator practices, and not suspect that I have any further motive, because I have none.

Thanks.

Comment: Why has this received a vote to close as "off-topic"?  A question about math.se moderator procedures is certainly on-topic for meta.math.se.

Comment: The question is whether or not the user who voted to close this meta post has consulted his thousands of fellow users before voting to close. :-)

Comment: The only people who can answer this question are the moderators. Isn't there a way to ask a moderator a question without posting it here on meta?

Comment: [There is, as a matter of fact.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) I'm not a moderator, obviously, but if precedent is anything to go by, in many cases moderators don't consult each other on something like simply closing a question (which can be overturned by regular users, but even so).

Comment: Moderators don't need to consult others about moderating the site, their judgement is (usually) sound and that's why they are moderators in the first place.

Comment: @Gerry I asked the question in a moderator flag last week, but received no reply.  I thought the answer might be of general interest,  so I posted it here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consulting others for every decision we make would not scale, so if we are sufficiently sure of our judgement, we act without consultation. The level of certainty that is considered sufficient depends of course on the graveness of the action to be performed, a suspension for example is more likely to be discussed among the moderators than things like question closures which, if people disagree with our decision, can be overturned by the community. But it is not too rare that we ask for confirmation before closing or reopening a question.

In the specific case mentioned in the question, I did not consult the other moderators before closing the question because a) I was sufficiently sure that the question was too broad ("Please share anything useful or fun that you know of concerning $\pi$.") and b) I didn't see any other moderator around at that time.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear and detailed answer.

Comment: It pleases me that the moderator team acts in this way. Considerate, but firm and confident. As I see it, we didn't bestow unto you these powers to let them gather dust. Use them!